# How can I "activate" and "deactivate" a LabelSet?

Tags: bokeh, python-3.7

I want to activate and deactivate a LabelSet by clicking a Button. Is there a simple way to realize that? I already tried an example by using the "visible" feature, but after deactivating i wasn't able to reactivate (show) the labelset again. It dispeared completely.

Something like that...

```py
def activate_labelset():
    ???



def activate_labelset():
    ???



plot = figure()
plot.circle(x='x', y='y', source=source, size=10, name='circles')

labels = LabelSet(x='x', y='y', text='text', level='glyph',
                  x_offset=1, y_offset=1, source=source, render_mode='css', 
                  text_font_style='bold', text_font_size='1vh', 
                  name='labelset')

plot.add_layout(labels)


button_activate = Button(label="activate", button_type="primary",
                         width=100, height=50)
button_activate.on_click(activate_labelset)


button_deactivate = Button(label="deactivate", button_type="primary", 
                           width=100, height=50)
button_deactivate.on_click(deactivate_labelset)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All renderers have a `.visible` property that you can set:

```
labels.visible = False # or True
```

Alternatively you could set `labels.text_alpha = 0` to make things invisible.

Comment: Ok, thanks! The ".text_alpha = 0" method works perfectly.